# Mysql a different selection set for each table when using JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have this JOIN statement

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table a  JOIN db.table2 b ON a.e_id = b.e_id WHERE amount='5' ");
```

Which selects all the columns from "table" but what I need to do is keep the select all for "table" and only include two columns from "table2" in the results.

Comment: You probably ought to specify which table has the column `amount`, if only for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"SELECT a.*,b.column1,b.column2 FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.e_id = b.e_id WHERE amount='5'"
```

just replace "column1" and "column2" with the fields that you need to pull in

Comment: I'm not sure why but adding the "a." before the * is causing a problem

Comment: are you recieving any errors. You can do     mysql_query(SQL_STATEMENT) or die(mysql_error($LINK_TO_DB));

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-100,100' at line 1

Comment: it appears that you are setting an offet,limit in your sql. It can't pull in rows starting at -100

Comment: actually this error seems to be down to some else in the query I left out, so your solution is fine.